# Angular - Fill dropdown based on selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, laravel, laravel-5

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-xs-2 type-image" ng-repeat='group in groups'>
     <a class="thumbnail" ng-click='selectItem(group)'>
        <img src="<% group.image %>" class="img-responsive">
     </a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-5 type-description" ng-bind-html="selectedItem.description | unsafe"></div>  

<div class="col-md-6 no-gutter">  
   <select ng-options="gurte.id for gurte in group.gurte"></select>  
</div>
```

**app.js**

```
app.controller('gurtController', function($scope, $http) {

$scope.groups = [];
$scope.loading = false;

$scope.init = function() {
    $scope.loading = true;
    $http.get('/api/groups').
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.groups = data;
            $scope.loading = false;

    });
}
$scope.selectItem = function(item) {
    $scope.selectedItem = item;
}
$scope.init();

});
```

How can I fill the select dropdown based on the selection in the upper block of the HTML?  Am I right, that the scope is still on "group" when I have selected it in the top or do I have to pass "group" to the select field somehow?

If needed I can provide the output from the API too. basically its:

```
Group  
  -id  
  -name  
  -gurte (relationship) ->  
      - id  
      - spalten (many to many; ) ->  
        - id  
        - name (this needs to go to the dropdown)  
        -> pivot -> spalten_value
```

Comment: Try once with `selectedItem.gurte` isntaed of `group.gurte`

Comment: not sure if case is the case `group.gurte` or `Group.gurte`

Comment: its group. and selectedItem. doesn't work :/